# What are the differences between Marlin and Pantheon Files?

Tags: pantheon-files, elementary-project

Marlin and Pantheon Files look similar—are they the same?

I couldn't find a good explanation anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two look similar because elementary [forked](http://archive.is/Stiqp) Pantheon Files from Marlin [in 2012](https://answers.launchpad.net/marlin/+question/193884) [after](https://web.archive.org/web/20121025053951*/http://2buntu.com/2012/04/26/marlin-is-dead-maintainer-needed/) the lead dev lost interest in the project. The dev [posted in May 2013](https://answers.launchpad.net/marlin/+question/227968) that the two were indistinguishable apart from some text changes and the removal of settings. (The dev had other thoughts on the politics of the project.) The Marlin project was [last updated](https://code.launchpad.net/marlin/+code?field.lifecycle=CURRENT&field.lifecycle-empty-marker=1&field.sort_by=most+recently+changed+first&field.sort_by-empty-marker=1) a month prior (April 2013), so it's safe to say that, even with its bugs, Files has subsumed its predecessor.

Pantheon Files works on other distributions, such as [Fedora](https://decathorpe.com/2016/11/06/a-report-on-packaging-pantheon-for-fedora/), though they may not be specifically supported.